# Hybrid Search SharePoint On-Prem Property Bag Property not Creating Crawled Properties

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, sharepoint-on-prem, sharepoint-search, hybrid-search

I have setup Cloud Hybrid Search and did a full crawl on on-prem Local SharePoint Sites content source.

After successful crawl completion I see all crawled properties for site/list columns created under online search schema. But I don't see the crawled properties for the on-prem sites property bag properties.

I also created a new property bag properties on on-prem sites and did a full crawl again. I don't see these properties either.

Do I need to take care of any additional steps or is this an issue?

Can someone give me your thoughts if you already gone through this scenario

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did set the property bag properties Indexed explicitly and did a full crawl again. It started showing up the crawled properties.

Example:

```
Set-PnPPropertyBagValue -Key "<<Property Name>>" -Value "<<property value>>" -Indexed
```

Comment: Did you do this for your online tenant?

Comment: This I did on on-prem